# What were this character's missing words?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the Season Six finale of *Game of Thrones*,

> in the second part of the Tower of Joy flashback, we see Lyanna Stark tell young Ned something, before saying "Robert will kill him, you know he will."

Do we have any lipreaders amongst us who could possibly work out what she was saying? Or was it more likely just gibberish and all done for dramatic effect?

Comment: Please don't post questions which are *entirely* spoilerblocks. At least the first phrase should be de-spoilered so that people know where to expect spoilers from - if somebody reads this question in years to come, they should know beforehand whether it contains spoilers from season 5, season 6, ot season 7.

Comment: It was a mistake on my part. I was going to edit it so it would only show the first sentence. Apologies. Also, misread "spoilerblocks" as "spoilerbollocks" haha